# Why can't I connect to the STM32F103C8 with j-link using swd?

Tags: stm32, linux, j-link

I am learning to work with stm32.

I have a stm32 "bluepill" for that. I have done a couple of simple projects with it.

But now I have a problem, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I found out that there is a program called ozone (for debugging) and it works on linux. I wanted to try it and bought a j-link.

But I ran into a problem. I can't connect and flash the stm32.

I tried to connect via console and ozone, but it doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

At the same time I can flash through normal stlink ...

**My console:**

```bash
└─■ JLinkGDBServer  -device STM32F103C8 -if SWD -speed 4000
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V7.60c Command Line Version
JLinkARM.dll V7.60c (DLL compiled Jan  7 2022 16:13:33)
Command line: -device STM32F103C8 -if SWD -speed 4000
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 STM32F103C8
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        4000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link V11 compiled Dec  9 2021 14:14:49
Hardware: V11.00
S/N: **********
Feature(s): GDB, RDI, FlashBP, FlashDL, JFlash
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.32 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...
ERROR: Could not connect to target.
Target connection failed. GDBServer will be closed...Restoring target state and closing J-Link connection...
Shutting down...
Could not connect to target.
Please check power, connection and settings.
```

**My ozone traceback:**

```bash
Disabled output of control characters
J-Link software found at:
Target core support plugin loaded.: /opt/SEGGER/Ozone_V326a/Plugins/Core/CorePluginARM.so
Project.SetDevice ("STM32F103C8");
Project.SetHostIF ("USB", "**********");
Project.SetTargetIF ("SWD");
Project.SetTIFSpeed ("4 MHz");
Project.AddSvdFile ("$(InstallDir)/Config/CPU/Cortex-M3.svd");
File path resolved: "$(InstallDir)/Config/CPU/Cortex-M3.svd" was found at "/opt/SEGGER/Ozone_V326a/Config/CPU/Cortex-M3.svd"
Project.AddSvdFile ("$(InstallDir)/Config/Peripherals/STM32F103xx.svd");
File path resolved: "$(InstallDir)/Config/Peripherals/STM32F103xx.svd" was found at "/opt/SEGGER/Ozone_V326a/Config/Peripherals/STM32F103xx.svd"
File.Open ("/home/iz/CLionProjects/test_blink_make/build/test_blink_make.bin");
Debug.Start();
Device "STM32F103C8" selected.
InitTarget() start
Can not attach to CPU. Trying connect under reset.
Connecting to CPU via connect under reset failed.
InitTarget() end
```

**My cubemx**
[image]

**My connection**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is blue pill self powered?

Comment: The blue pill is powered by j-link . I have a Chinese j-link.

Comment: I added a picture.